# Derivative of trace w.r.t. scalar

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

I am trying to take the derivative of the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \,a} \left[-\frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \mbox{tr} \left\lbrace \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_{p\times p} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right) \left( a^2\mathbf{A}_{d \times d} - a \mathbf{B}_{d\times d}+\mathbf{I}_{d\times d}\right) \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right)^T
\right\rbrace \right]$$

I have done some search on the internet but have not been able to find a way of taking the derivative w.r.t. a scalar inside the trace.

I looked onto [this page](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/calculus.html#deriv_quad), and almost all formulas are for matrices.

Comment: the matrices don't depend on $a$? then just use linearity of trace

Comment: Differentiate _inside_ of the trace, i.e.
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \left[\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} tr \left\lbrace 
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_{p\times p} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right) \left( 2a\mathbf{A}_{d \times d} - \mathbf{B}_{d\times d}+\mathbf{I}_{d\times d}\right) \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right)^T
\right\rbrace \right]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} tr \left\lbrace 
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_{p\times p} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right) \left( a^2\mathbf{A}_{d \times d} - a \mathbf{B}_{d\times d}+\mathbf{I}_{d\times d}\right) \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right)^T
\right\rbrace 
\\=
\left[-\frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} tr \left\lbrace 
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_{p\times p} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right) \mathbf{A}_{d \times d} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right)^T
\right\rbrace \right]a^2 
-
\left[-\frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} tr \left\lbrace 
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_{p\times p} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right) \mathbf{B}_{d \times d} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right)^T
\right\rbrace \right]a
+
\left[-\frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} tr \left\lbrace 
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}_{p\times p} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right) \mathbf{I}_{d \times d} \left(\mathbf{Y}_{p\times d}-\mathbf{M}_{p\times d} \right)^T
\right\rbrace \right] $$
now apply formula for differentiating $f(a)=Aa^2 + Ba + C$.